# How to subtract 1 second in the hhmmss format

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

```
sart_time   end_time
....
11:57:53    11:58:19
11:58:30    11:58:30
....
```

I want to do:

`11:58:30` is an example.

If the `sart_time` equal to the `end_time`, `start_time` = `end_time - 1` however, the code can't minus `1`s directly.

The other problem is although the cell shows `11:58:30`, in Excel actually it's `11:58:30 AM` (shows in the top of Excel page).  I am not sure it affects the result or not.

What I wrote is:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow - 1
  If Range("E" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value Then
  Range("E" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value-1
End If
Next i
```

I tried `-1`, `-00:00:01`, `-time(0,0,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember time is a decimal to Excel and by subtracting 1 you are subtracting a full day and not 1 second.

Use `TimeSerial()`:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow - 1
  If Range("E" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value Then
     Range("E" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value - TimeSerial(0,0,1)
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's amazing.

Comment: @PhoenixNing please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sure! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
    Range(“E” & I).Value = DateAdd(“S”,-1,Range(“F” & I).Value)